# juniper srx-100 firewall configuration

Tags: firewall

I am configuring proxy-arp and after commit the following error occurs.

```
Proxy ARP IP address range [203.215.166.85 203.215.166.86] overlaps with interface IP address range [203.215.166.86 203.215.166.86] defined on interface 'fe-0/0/0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy-Arp is only required when the IP is not on the interface you're configuring.

Similar problems:
[Juniper Forum](http://www.juniperforum.com/index.php?topic=23461.0)[Juniper Forum Example 2](http://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/set-proxy-arp-destination-nat/td-p/59584)

Comment: Please provide and example so that i may get your point. not clear to me.